# how to show full path of selected image in magento frontend and store that path in database

Tags: magento-1.9, php, html

I have created form in which we can select an image using 
 and i want to store path in database.

[image: here i can successfully added image and i can store the name in database also.but what i want is instead of showing only name it should show the full path of that image]

and when i submit the data in database it should save the same path in database.
and i have further operations in admin also.. but now atlst i have to show all this

Answer (score 0):

In your case,you have to get image name from your database table.
Then get the base url of your website as:-

```
$this->getBaseUrl
```

And then your image folder structure as:-

```
pub/media/<Image Folder>
```

At last, concatinate the three results as:-

```
$this->getBaseUrl./pub/media/<Image Folder>.<image_name>
```

this will take you to your image.
Hope this helps you.